# Laravel 4.0 to 5.7 migration

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-4, migrate

I have a Laravel 4.0 application. Is it possible to migrate this instance to Laravel 5.7? What are the impacts of this on the system and how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a possibility if you upgrade it to 4.2 and then use https://laravelshift.com/ to get it to 5.7. It will cost you somewhat though.